# How to make table in VueJs and add values being recieved by MSSQL database in .NET Core web application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I'm creating a table inside a .NET Core Web Application with several rows and columns and the contents are being called using `MSSQL server` with a WEB API

Since I have more than one row and column, I need a for loop inside my `<div> tag`

This is what I was able to find.

```
v-for="(FirstName, LastName, UserID) in tableData>
```

Comment: Then, What's your question?

Comment: That does not work, do I use v-for or v-in

Comment: how are you recieving it from the MSSQL server ?
What you really need to do is, to convert it into a javascript object and then loop over it. 
You will loop over it like 
v-for="obj in tableData">
{{obj.FirstName}}

Comment: I am receiving the contents from a WebAPI. I should have mentioned, this is a .NET Core application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are attempting to loop over multiple values from the `tableData`,  you can destructure it like this:

```
<tr v-for="{FirstName, LastName, UserID} in tableData" :key="UserID">
<td> {{FirstName}} </td>
<td> {{LastName}} </td>
<td> {{UserID}} </td>
</tr>
```

However, your question does not seem clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very narrative. But if you are looking to loop over the result of your query and generate your rows dynamically:

```
    <tr v-for="user in tableData" :key="user.id">
          <td>{{user.id}}</td>
          <td>{{user.name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    </tr>
```

The properties depending on the rows you have in your tables & the rows you want to return (.id, .name, .email are just examples here)